# Is there a word for when two functions can be reduced to each other?

Tags: function, reduction

I have two functions, let's say foo and bar, and I can reduce foo to bar and bar to foo. By that I mean I can use bar to compute foo if I change the input to bar or the output from it. And same for computing bar using foo.

Is there a word for this relation between foo and bar?

For example, in math terms:

```
f(x) = x + 1
```

and

```
g(x) = x - 1
```

I can then write f using g as:

```
f(x) = g(x + 2)
```

and g using f as:

```
g(x) = f(x - 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple words for this, but here is one:

"Modular Programming: Modular programming is a software design technique that emphasizes separating the functionality of a program into independent, interchangeable modules, such that each contains everything necessary to execute only one aspect of the desired functionality."

Basically, each function should do one and one thing only. If both foo and bar do the same thing, then they should be in one function. But if foo and bar do separate things, then they should be two separate functions.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm asking for. I'm not asking for a paradigm that does something similar.

When I talk about 2 functions that can be computed using each other, I mean something like (in heavily simplified terms with mathematical functions) `f(x) = x + 1` and `g(x) = x - 1`. I can then write f using g: `f(x) = g(x + 2)` and g using f: `g(x) = f(x - 2)`.

Comment: Do you know what the term would be in math terms? Because with programming it's about the same.

Comment: Usually you don't even want functions like this.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how they are named in math, which is why I'm asking it. Also, yes you wouldn't want to use these exact functions, but they are very simple examples of what I'm thinking about. If you want something more complicated then moeb and fix seem to fit the above definition according to [this article](https://github.com/quchen/articles/blob/master/loeb-moeb.md).

Comment: Oh ok understood. Sorry I probably didn't answer your question at all then. As this seems more like a math related issue, I would post on http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Yeah, it seems partially appropriate for math. too. So I'll try that.

Comment: Sounds great. I hope I helped at least a little. I hope you get an answer to your question :)